# Prevent fork() from copying sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, fork

I have the following situation (pseudocode):

```
function f:
    pid = fork()
    if pid == 0:
        exec to another long-running executable (no communication needed to that process)
    else:
        return "something"
```

`f` is exposed over a [XmlRpc++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpcpp/) server. When the function is called over XML-RPC, the parent process prints "done closing socket" after the function returned "something". But the XML-RPC client hangs as long as the child process is still running. When I kill the child process, the XML-RPC client correctly finishes the RPC call.

It seems to me that I'm having a problem with `fork()` copying socket descriptors to the child process (parent called `closesocket` but child still owns a reference -> connection still established). How can I circumvent this?

**EDIT:** I read about `FD_CLOEXEC` already, but can't I *force* all descriptors to be closed on `exec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't force all file descriptors to be closed on exec.  You will need to loop over all unwanted file descriptors in the child after the `fork()` and close them.  Unfortunately, there isn't an easy, portable, way to do that - the usual approach is to use `getrlimit()` to get the current value of `RLIMIT_NOFILE` and loop from 3 to that number, trying `close()` on each candidate.

If you are happy to be Linux-only, you can read the `/proc/self/fd/` directory to determine the open file descriptors and close them (except 0, 1 and 2 - which should either be left alone or reopened to `/dev/null`).

Comment: Or be portable and just set `FD_CLOEXEC` on not needed descriptors before `exec(2)`.

Comment: I implemented it with the proc filesystem now, falling back to the `getrlimit` solution if necessary (if /proc/self/fd doesn't exist). Just one question: Is there a difference between `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, ...)-1` and `sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)`?

Comment: @Nikolai: Sure, that or just `close()` them - but that assumes that you *know* what file descriptors are open, and from the context it appears that isn't the case (since they're opened by third-party software).

Comment: @AndiDog: I don't believe they're the same in general.  Also `sysconf()` can return -1 for "no limit", and `getrlimit` has `RLIMIT_INFINITY`, which complicates things somewhat.