# os.execute without inheriting parent's fds

Tags: sockets, shell, lua, exec, fork

I have a problem analogous to the one described here:
[Prevent fork() from copying sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179619/prevent-fork-from-copying-sockets)

Basically, inside my Lua script I'm spawning another script which:

- doesn't require communicating with my script either way
- continues running after my script had finished
- is a 3rd party program, code of which I have no control over

The problem is that my Lua script opens a TCP socket to listen on a specific port and after it's quit and **despite** an explicit `server:close()` the child (or more specifically its children) holds onto the socket and keeps the port open (in LISTEN state) preventing my script from running again.

Here's example code that demonstrates the problem:

```
require('socket')

print('listening')
s = socket.bind("*", 9999)
s:settimeout(1)

while true do
    print('accepting connection')
    local c = s:accept()
    if c then
            c:settimeout(1)
            local rec = c:receive()
            print('received ' .. rec)
            c:close()
            if rec == "quit" then break end
            if rec == "exec" then 
                    print('running ping in background')
                    os.execute('sleep 10s &')
                    break
            end     
    end
end
print('closing server')
s:close()
```

If I run the above script and `echo quit | nc localhost 9999` everything works well - program quits and port is closed.

However if I do `echo exec | nc localhost 9999` the program quits but the port is blocked by the spawned `sleep` (as confirmed by `netstat -lpn`) until it exits.

How do I tackle this in the simplest possible manner, preferably without adding any extra dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution which utilizes the fact that `os.execute(cmd)` runs `cmd` in a `shell`, which, as it turns out, is capable of closing file descriptors as seen here:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/ash (section *Redirections* )
- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

---

For example (tested in `ash`):

```
    exec 3<&-                                      # closes fd3
    exec 3<&- 4<&-                                 # closes fd3 and fd4
    eval exec `seq 1 255 | sed -e 's/.*/&<\&-/'`   # closes all file descriptors
```

---

So in my `luasocket` based example it's enough to replace:

```
    os.execute('sleep 10s &')
```

with:

```
    os.execute("eval exec `seq 1 255 | sed -e 's/.*/&<\\&-/'`; sleep 10s &")
```

This closes all file descriptors, including my server socket, before executing the actual command (here `sleep 10s`) so that it doesn't hog the port after my script exits. It also has the bonus of taking care of  `stdout` and `stderr` redirection.

This is much more compact and uncomplicated than working around `Lua`'s limitations and doesn't require any extra dependencies. Thanks go to *#uclibc* where I got some brilliant help with final shell syntax from the embedded linux crew.

Comment: Well done!  Where there's a will, there's a way :-)  Glad you came back with an update, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're going to be able to do it like that if you want to keep the `s:close`  only at the end of the whole program.  You might succeed by moving it up into before `os.execute`, since you're `break`ing anyway (but you're probably not doing this in your real program).  **Edit for clarity**: The actual problem is that the only place you're spawning a subprocess in this case, is by using `os.execute()`, and you have no control over the child environment of sleep, in which everything is inherited from the main program, including socket and file descriptors.

So, the canonical way to do this on POSIX is to use `fork(); close(s); exec();`, instead of `system()` (aka, `os.execute`) as `system()`/`os.execute` will hang on to the current process state during execution, and you won't be able to close it while blocked in the sub-process.

So, a suggestion would be to grab [luaposix](http://luaforge.net/projects/luaposix/), and use its `posix.fork()` and `posix.exec()` functionality, and calling `s:close()` in the `fork`ed child process.  Shouldn't be so bad, since you're already using an external package by relying upon `luasocket`.

---

**EDIT**: Here's heavily commented code to do it with luaposix:

```
require('socket')
require('posix')

print('listening')
s = socket.bind("*", 9999)
s:settimeout(1)

while true do
    print('accepting connection')
    local c = s:accept()
    if c then
            c:settimeout(1)
            local rec = c:receive()
            print('received ' .. rec)
            c:close()
            if rec == "quit" then break end
            if rec == "exec" then
                    local pid = posix.fork()
                    if pid == 0 then
                        print('child: running ping in background')
                        s:close()
                        -- exec() replaces current process, doesn't return.
                        -- execp has PATH resolution
                        rc = posix.execp('sleep','60s');
                        -- exec has no PATH resolution, probably "more secure"
                        --rc = posix.exec('/usr/bin/sleep','60s');
                        print('exec failed with rc: ' .. rc);
                    else
                        -- if you want to catch the SIGCHLD:
                        --print('parent: waiting for ping to return')
                        --posix.wait( pid )
                        print('parent: exiting loop')
                    end
                    break;
            end
    end
end
print('closing server')
s:close()
```

This closes the socket in the child process before calling `exec`, and the `netstat -nlp` output shows the system is correctly no longer listening on port 9999 when the parent exits.

P.S. The line `print('exec failed with rc: ' .. rc);` complained about a type problem once when exec failed.  I don't actually know lua, so you'll have to fix that. :)  Furthermore, `fork()` can fail, returning -1.  Probably should check for that in your main code, too, for completeness.

Comment: OK, it's progress tho I was secretly hoping it wasn't going to come to `fork()ing`. `luaposix` is fine as a dep as it's  built into the interpreter on the target platform - OpenWrt.

The problem with our example `sleep` hogging the port is gone but has been replaced with 2 more:
- if you take away the `break` after `fork` and send `exec` to the port `s:accept()` no longer times out and it's meant to be non-blocking.
- if you replace `sleep` with `ping` its output goes to the same pty as script output which is undesirable.
These might go beyond the scope of original question but are related.

Comment: Sorry, myopenid went down for a bit there.  I played more with the code per your other questions, and I think this is beyond my lua knowledge.  I tried `io.output('/dev/null')` and `io.stdout:close()`, before `execp()`, with no luck.  Here's some related information: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466064) and the [lua manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html).  On `wait()`, I checked the source for `luaposix`, and it doesn't implement `WNOHANG`, so that might be a problem for non-blocking.  If no one else responds to this, you might post another Q on these issues.

Comment: I found a solution to the stdout problem here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/HiddenFeatures. This closes the standard file: `local f=assert(io.open '/dev/null'); debug.setfenv(io.stdout, debug.getfenv(f)); f:close(); assert(io.stdout:close())`

Comment: Now I just need to figure out why after the `fork()`/`exec()` the timeout on `s:accept()` isn't respected (checked with `strace`) and execution is blocked until a client connects. And this is how an `os.execute` single line turns into an elaborate function just because I want to have control socket. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Not that I know of.  When calling `os.execute` (which is `system()`), it still does a fork/exec/wait in that call, but you lose control over the environment inherited by the child proc, so you don't have a chance to close file/socket descriptors, etc.  If there's a way around it, it'd be something lua-specific.  Dunno why it's forgetting your timeout.  If lua can use `select` (with all args), you can use its timeout value, and check when your `s` becomes readable (client connecting).  Another idea is if `setsockopt` is in `socket`, it has an `O_NONBLOCK` option.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX approach is to set your file descriptors with the FD_CLOEXEC flag, using [fcntl (2)](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fcntl). When set, all sub-processes will not inherit the file descriptors marked with that flag.

Stock Lua doesn't have the fcntl feature but it's possible to add it with the [lua posix](https://github.com/rrthomas/luaposix) module as introduced in previous answers. To take your example, you would have to change the starts as such:

```
require('socket')
require('posix')
s = socket.bind("*", 9999)
posix.setfl(s, posix.FD_CLOEXEC)
s:settimeout(1)
```

Note that I didn't find the FD_CLOEXEC constant in the luaposix source so you might have to add it by hand as well.